# data binding to custom dropdown with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am creating a custom dropdown element, with following HTML and some CSS:

```
<div id="dd" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 wrapper-dropdown-3 left-divider" tabindex="1">
    <span>Age</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">\
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>1 Month Old</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>11 Month Old</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But How do I bind the value selected by the dropdown to some vue variable?

I tried `<span v-bind="dataVar">Age</span>`, but `dataVar` does not changes when you change value of dropdown. I had defined `dataVar` like follwoing

```
data: function() { 
  return { 
    dataVar: ''
  }
},
```

How do I have selected value of dropdown in `dataVar` variable?

Working drop down in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/28gjwvut/3/), in `Go to Foo` view.

Comment: Why don't create a Vue component?

Comment: @GerardReches that seems promising, but still how will I bind a variable as value in HTML is being changed by javascript.

Comment: Can you please add to the question what you want to achieve? I'm not understanding what do you mean with bind this piece of code to a vue variable.

Comment: Can't you just use a method for that? updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xzkv7ko/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrite you custom select.
You need use: `v-model`. Yes it's work not only for inputs. [See docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props)

Example usage:

```
 <h3>Selected: {{ selected.name }}</h3>

 <custom-select :options="options"
                value-key="id" 
                label-key="name"
                v-model="selected"></custom-select>
             
             
 <div style="margin-top: 40px">
     <h3>Wihtout labels, for simple values, like numbers</h3>
  
     <custom-select :options="options"
                    v-model="selected"></custom-select>
 </div>
```

Enjoy [**DEMO**](http://playcode.io/dropdown_vue?tabs=output&app.html&custom-select.js) with clean source code

Comment: I want to control opening of dropdown from parent component, How can I do this with this approach, should I make `opened` as `props` or pass another `prop` and have watcher over it?

Comment: Yes, make "opened" as prop with "default: false".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090515/how-to-populate-form-depend-on-the-dropdown-selection/53091501?noredirect=1#comment93081598_53091501

Answer (score 0):

modifications:

1.`function DropDown (el,onChange) {  this.onChange = onChange`

2.`obj.opts.on('click', function () {  ....    obj.onChange(obj.val)`

3.`<span> this is foo </span>  <span> my value is {{selected}} </span>\`

https://jsfiddle.net/postor/z79b0ksk/2/

there are two ways for this case:

1. I choose to use bind change and use vm.$set, since you have the change handle already
2. you can choose to make selections inside Vue management, that would be something like `data:()=>{selected:null,options:['one month','11 month']}` `<div v-for="opt in options" v-on:click="selected=opt">`

```js
/* global $:true */
function DropDown (el,onChange) {
  this.dd = el
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span')
  this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li')
  this.val = ''
  this.index = -1
  this.initEvents()
  this.onChange = onChange
}

DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function () {
    var obj = this

    obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active')
      return false
    })

    obj.opts.on('click', function () {
      var opt = $(this)
      obj.val = opt.text()
      obj.index = opt.index()
      obj.placeholder.text(obj.val)
      obj.onChange(obj.val)
    })
  },
  getValue: function () {
    return this.val
  },
  getIndex: function () {
    return this.index
  }
}


// Define some components
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>\
        <div id="dd" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 wrapper-dropdown-3 left-divider" tabindex="1">\
        <span>Age</span>\
        <ul class="dropdown">\
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>1 Month Old</a></li>\
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>11 Month Old</a></li>\
        </ul>\
      </div>\
  <div class="card row" >\
  <div class="col-xs-5" style="height: 100px; background-color: red; position: fixed;">\
  <span> this is foo </span>\
    </div>\
      <div class="col-xs-7" style="height: 100px; background-color: Yellow">\
  <span> this is foo </span>\
  <span> my value is {{selected}} </span>\
    </div>\
  </div>\
</div>',
  data: function() { return {  
   selected:null
  }},
  mounted () {
  new DropDown($(this.$el.querySelector('#dd')),(val)=>{
    this.selected = val
   })    
  }
};

const  Bar = {
  template: '<p>This is bar!</p>',
  data: function() { return {  
  }}
};


// Create a router instance.
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    } else {
      return {x: 0, y: 0}
    }
    },
    routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090515/how-to-populate-form-depend-on-the-dropdown-selection/53091501?noredirect=1#comment93081598_53091501